# Converting Java GET request into GET request in debugger

Tags: java, json, http

I extracted the following code from a non-working app and I am trying to debug the request.

```
    HttpGetWithEntity request = new HttpGetWithEntity();
request.setURI(new URI(baseURL));
JsonObject reqSaveObject = new JsonObject();
reqSaveObject.addProperty("goal", "request");
reqSaveObject.addProperty("user", user_string);
reqSaveObject.addProperty("key", key_string);
reqSaveObject.addProperty("project", project_type);
```

I am trying to build the request in a debugger (Fiddler / Postman), and I don't understand how I am supposed to structure the request.

I understand that user_string, key_string and project_type refer to string and I know those values.

Any information will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is a GET request with request body, in your case JSON formatted. So in Postman you would insert something in the following style as request body:

```
{
    "goal": "request",
    "property": "value",
    "property2": "value2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up figuring this out thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56985966/13305012