# Get request works with postman but with browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, axios, cors

Get request sent from POSTMAN works but when sent from browser fails.
At the backend req.body is undefined even after using bodyparser middleware.
The same requet when sent from the POSTMAN works.

This is the axios call from the frontend.

```
await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/authenticate`, {
            accesstoken: localStorage.getItem("accesstoken")
        },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch'
                }
            })
            .then((res) => console.log(res))
            .catch((err) => {
                localStorage.removeItem("accesstoken");
                console.log(err)
            });
```

This is the backend auth handler

```
const isAuthenticated = (req,res,next)=>{
    const accesstoken = req.body.accesstoken;
    console.log(req.body);
    if(!accesstoken)
   {
    
    res.json({msg:"No token provided"});
   }
   else
   {
    jwt.verify(accesstoken,process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRETE,(err,decoded)=>{
        if(err)
        {
            
            res.json({msg:"Invalid token"});
        }
        else
         next();
        
    });
   }

}
```

These are the cors options

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:["http://localhost:3000","http://192.168.0.86:3000"],
  optionsSuccessStatus:200,
  credentials:true,
  allowHeaders:["Content-Type"]
}));
```

Comment: Can you capture both requests (say, with tcpdump or wireshark) and diff them?

Comment: Thank you for your response @AllanWind , actually i am bit unaware of tcpdump or wireshark but i can show you the destructuring of request object in backend.

Comment: Thank you for responding @AjeetShah, actually it works fine with POSTMAN but when sent from browser it gives {msg:"No token provided"},in POSTMAN it returns {msg:"User has been authenticated"}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you meant to do `axios.post`:

```
await axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/authenticate`, {
  accesstoken: localStorage.getItem("accesstoken")
},
  {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch'
      }
  })
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => {
      localStorage.removeItem("accesstoken");
      console.log(err)
  });
```

Comment: Thank you @AjeetShah it served my purpose, but i am curious to know  how it worked fine with POSTMAN, will you please explain?

Comment: Did you really use `GET` in postman? You can't send data using `GET`.

Comment: Hey @AjeetShah. It's possible to do so using Postman.

Answer (score 2):

The method signature you are using for `axios.get` applies to `axios.post` where the second parameter is the **request body**. This doesn't hold true for `axios.get`. You can pass **query paramters** as second argument of `axios.get`. Postman is allowing you to make GET requests with body and the server is okay with that but it isn't advised to do so. For your use case of authentication, use **POST**.

Comment: @makarand You should accept this answer. In my answer, I assumed you made a Typo. Also, you may want to read this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/42068572/2873538 . Go with `POST` for sending data until everyone (MDN, Postman, Browsers, HTTP client libraries etc.) start allowing `data` in `GET`.

Comment: Absolutely no problem @AjeetShah , I have made the changes and it is working flawlessly , thank you.